# Storing some values for later use - iPhone application

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone application that does an action. Let's call it X. I'd like to have a pop up that asks the user if they want to rate my application after they have performed action X ten times. How can I keep track of this? Meaning, if they close the application the value will still be available. Do I need to keep a text file and update the value and write to a file each time or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults`.

You can do something like this to retrieve the value:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int timesOpened = [defaults integerForKey:@"timesOpened"];
```

To save a value you do:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int timesOpened = [defaults integerForKey:@"timesOpened"];
[defaults setInteger:(timesOpened + 1) forKey:@"timesOpened"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [L0SolicitReview](http://infinite-labs.net/blog/l0solicitreview-or-asking-happy-users-to-share-their-joy). It does this, only a little bit different (still in line with what you described, just a few extra constraints). Best of all, it's done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is, use SQLite3 which is already included in iOS SDK. This works for people who are more familiar with SQL than Cocoa.